# How to use GoogleMap NMP package from JavaScript in HTML under Apache environment?

Tags: javascript, typescript, google-maps-api-3

Ok, This is pretty much a dumb question but I couldn't find any answer so dropping here.

I recently came back to web app project that uses Google Map Cluserer JavaScript Library. I've done it before, it was pretty straight forward, I was able to integrate Cluserer within a couple of hours or so. But it is written in TypeScript now, which I never used (but not concerned about language point of view). I installed it under project web dir using nmp thing then I'm stuck there. How can I use them from JavaScript in HTML? Do I need to compile it and copy to my web dir manually? Or is it auto compiled when it's called from JavaScript?

Google's Doc says I should do below at somewhere(I assumed it's web dir):

```
npm install @googlemaps/markerclusterer
```

Then call below from JS:

```
import { MarkerClusterer } from "@googlemaps/markerclusterer";

const markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer({ map, markers });
```

But I got error below:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "@googlemaps/markerclusterer". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".
```

I found that I can get JavaScript version from CDN and I was able to run Cluserer in my project, everything is fine now, but I'd like to know how to use TypeScript version under Apache environment.

Could anyone enlighten me please?

Thanks!

-- JK

Comment: Have you tried what the error says there? `references must start with either "/", "./", or "../"`